# handling exceptions in service fabric

Tags: c#, azure, exception, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I have an a controller method in my api calling a service which throws a custom exception.

```
customException : 
    public class DematerialisationException : Exception
{
    private static readonly string DefaultMessage = "An error occurred during dematerialisation.";

    public DematerialisationException() : base(DefaultMessage)
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(string message) : base(message) 
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(Exception inner) : base (DefaultMessage, inner)
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(string message, Exception inner) : base (message, inner)
    { }
}
```

the method called in the service directly throws the exception :

```
public async Task<LiasseDetails> CreateLiasseAsync(LiasseCreate liasseData) => 
throw new DematerialisationException();
```

then the caller : 
[image]

I would have expected ex3 to be hit instead it's ex2 as you can see in the screenshot. the innerException is in the correct type, so why is the wrong breakpoint hit? What did I do wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the variable watcher, you can see that a `ServiceException` is thrown when getting the value of `InnerException`, this happened because the exception object could not be serialized.
So try to add the attribute `[Serializable()]` to `DematerialisationException` class :

```
[Serializable()]
 public class DematerialisationException : Exception
{
    private static readonly string DefaultMessage = "An error occurred during dematerialisation.";

    public DematerialisationException() : base(DefaultMessage)
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(string message) : base(message) 
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(Exception inner) : base (DefaultMessage, inner)
    { }

    public DematerialisationException(string message, Exception inner) : base (message, inner)
    { }
}
```

Comment: I get a serialization exception if I do that : Failed to deserialize and get remote exception  System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The constructor to deserialize an object of type 'Inovatic.SF.Windows.DematerialisationCore.Model.Exceptions.DematerialisationException' was not found

Comment: yes, that was it, didn't realize it was a serialization problem, thank you